# How do I create a mathematical formula for a finite sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have this sequence of values and want to create a formula  to calculate serially all factors for X values ranging between 1 and 8. Can somebody point me the direction please?

```
if (X<=8){
    $factor : 0.45
    }
    if (X<=7){
     $factor : 0.5
    }
    if (X<=6){
     $factor : 0.58
    }
    if (X<=5){
     $factor : 0.64
    }
    if (X<=4){
     $factor : 0.75
    }
    if (X<=3){
     $factor : 0.9
    }
    if (X<=2){
     $factor : 1.3
    }
    if (X<=1){
     $factor : 2.3
}
```

Comment: Does this have something to do with Wolfram *Mathematica* or are you looking for [Math.SE]?  If the latter I shall migrate your question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes indeed sorry I' am wrong here. Are you able to move the question?

Comment: Moved as requested.

Comment: Oh, I see David edited this before the move.  I should have corrected that first.  Sorry to all.

Answer (score 1):

`f[x_] := Piecewise[{
{2.3, x<=1}, {1.3, x<=2}, {0.9, x<=3}, {0.75,x<=4}, 
{0.64, x<=5}, {0.58, x<=6}, {0.5, x<=7}, {0.45,x<=8}
}];`

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0,8}]
```

[image]

$
\begin{cases}
 2.3 & x\leq 1 \\
 1.3 & x\leq 2 \\
 0.9 & x\leq 3 \\
 0.75 & x\leq 4 \\
 0.64 & x\leq 5 \\
 0.58 & x\leq 6 \\
 0.5 & x\leq 7 \\
 0.45 & x\leq 8
\end{cases}
$